# Setting up a basic firewall for 1st time user

Tags: firewall

Could anyone tell me some basic commands to set up my firewall. I already have ufw. What commands should I use for a basic security?

Comment: Did you see the manual page of ufw? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: already used this guide? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Answer (score 1):

Use mannual page for ufw.

- Type  'man uwf' in your terminal window.

Comment: This is the same as the comments given above..